# SSL Connection to mysql database using OCI Data integration REQUIRE X509 flag

Tags: mysql, ssl, database

I have a data integration requirement to connect and retrieve data from mysql database using SSL,the user am using to connect is created is with REQUIRE X509 flag so in the connection i need to provide certificate and ca and key,the ETL (Data Integration) tool am using is OCI data integration managed service which have support to enable SSL when creating mysql database connection but there is no option of providing the ca and client certificate and key -REQUIRE X509 Option-,i cannot edit the user as this is required for security reasons, is there any way that will allow me connect to his database from OCI Data integration or any work around that will allow me to achieve this.

i have read about mysql router but i need few leads to work my way.